# Angularjs Directive -Get Element By ID

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have tried everything.

Instead of this:

```
var table = e.target.nextElementSibling
```

I want to use this:

```
var table = angular.element(document).find('#tabletarget');
```

or:

```
var table = angular.element(document).find('tabletarget');
```

But it's giving me an error as undefined. How can I select this specific table instead of blindly seeking for the next element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

angular.element(document.getElementByID('tabletarget'));
OR
angular.element(document.querySelector('#tabletarget'));